# PIC10F206 - p10f206.inc file not found

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I followed a tutorial to get into pic microcontrollers. 
But all code in tutorial supply me with errors. 
For example if I use this code as a first line of my assembly file:
`#include "p10f206.inc"`
I get the following error:
`'p10f206.inc' file not found`

Comment: try: #INCLUDE <p10f206.inc> ;

Comment: `"file"` means "this is a file you provide."  `<file>` means "this is a library file."

Comment: When I write ```include``` in capital letters it creates a "syntax error". When I use angle brackets I get the same ```file not found``` error.

Comment: Maybe that isn't the best tutorial.

Comment: Which assembler toolset are you using? A search of *Microchip MPASM Suite* shows **p10f206.inc** file name. A few different versions of these include files have various inception dates of 2013 to 2016, but they all have the same filename. A different toolchain than **Microchip** might name their include files differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will repeat my answer to a similar question on StackOverflow:

Microchip replaced its old assembler with a new one in the latest releases of XC8. There are lots of changes, including the syntax, which is hard to summarize in this answer. You need to refer to the manual of the new assembler. Unfortunately, most of the examples you can find on internet are not valid anymore.

For example, you need just `#include "xc.inc"` at the beginning. Absolute memory allocation is not supported anymore. Configs also have a different syntax, like `CONFIG WRT = OFF`. And a lot more... Again, you need to refer to the manual.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <pic10f206.inc>` does not create an error.
So it's "pic" instead of "p". 
I still have more errors though.

Comment: maybe show you errors in a new question. And please remember: MPASM is not included in MPLAX 5.4 and up. You had to use the assembler in xc8.